# Performance Difference between index on two columns vs conditional index

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

I have a decently large postgres table with a few billion rows.

However the table could be partitioned by one column (`type`)

Should we prefer:

An index with two columns

```
create nonclustered index ix_index1 on table1(type, string_urn_id)
```

or a conditional index

```
create nonclustered index ix_index1_alternative on table1(string_urn_id) WHERE type = 'type1'
create nonclustered index ix_index1_alternative2 on table1(string_urn_id) WHERE type = 'type2'
create nonclustered index ix_index1_alternative3 on table1(string_urn_id) WHERE type = 'type3'
....
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no statement `create nonclustered index` in PostgreSQL.

What is better depends on the definition of "better". From a maintenance perspective, the single index is better, because you won't have to create a new index whenever you add a new `type`.

From a performance perspective, only a benchmark with realistic data can tell. Planning time will increase with many indexes, but query performance may be a tad better.

If you partition the table, query performance will decrease, but you can do with a single partitioned index on `string_urn_id`.